# CSS selector for a div

Tags: css

I have a number of `DIVs` on the page with `class="row"`. I need a selector for one that had a child div with `id="test"`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12">
    <div id="test">
      This is a test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I select that particular row?

```
div.row div#test
```

did not work for me.

I tried accessing it using

```
$('div.row div#test ').show();
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: Since IDs **must** be unique, `#test` will suffice

Comment: `$('#test ').show();` did not work either... When I inspect the html, `display:none` for that element

Comment: Are you repeating IDs? If you want the grandparent, then use .`parent().parent()` or `.closest('.row')`

Comment: Why do you leave that blank space? try with $('div.row div#test').show();
Or you can try a jQuery approach with $('div.row').find('div#test').show();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.row').has('div#test').show()
```

With `$('div.row')` you get the row's divs. The method 'has('div#test')` applies a filter on these elements but still returns the row divs. See [jQuery.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

Here is an example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Glia_/xpvt214o/873566/)

Comment: Please explain your answer, provide context, and / or links to documentation of the features that make this work.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works for you?

```
$('#test').parent().parent()
```

Answer (score -1):

You would only need to specify..... #test

Comment: If the id is repeated in the page more times, specifying it won't do the trick

Comment: ID's should be unique and only used once. If you want it used more than once use a class.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery `.find` helper to let it work with one or multiple same ids:
`$('div.row').find('div#test').show();`